# Animated lines in Google maps api v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to draw a animated line using Google Maps API v3

it would be along the side of the road with moving arrows showing the direction of driving.

```
------------------
| > > > > > > >  |
------------------
```

I hope i made myself clear enough.

Comment: Using symbol, you can animate marker(s) on polyline. Check out here.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-animate

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates what you have so far.

Comment: one important thing to remember is to use the browser functionality for requesting animation frame so that the process does not go crazy in the background: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_with_requestAnimationFrame.htm Here is one example of how you can do this: view-source:http://kaskaderc.github.io/maps_samples/io_html_demos/symbols_animation.html